# Expected `&str`, found `&&str`

Tags: arrays, rust

Here is my code:

```
let mut i = 0;
let mut deck: [[&str; 2]; 56] = [[""; 2]; 56]; //Default::default();
for suit in suits.iter() {
   for rank in ranks.iter() {
        deck[i] = [suit, rank];
        i += 1;
   }
}
```

This is the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:37:23
   |
37 |             deck[i] = [suit, rank];
   |             -------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `str`, found `&str`
   |             |
   |             expected due to the type of this binding
   |
   = note: expected array `[&str; 2]`
              found array `[&&str; 2]`
```

I am unsure what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `iter()` produces an iterator over `&T`, and in this case that the element type (`T`) is `&str`, it is `&&str` (double reference). But `deck` is an array (of arrays of) `&str`, not `&&str`.

The fix is simple: since `&str` is `Copy`, you just need to dereference it:

```rust
deck[i] = [*suit, *rank];
```

Comment: Or use `suits.iter().copied()`

Comment: An even easier solution is to simply omit the `.iter()`; `suits` and `ranks` seem to be arrays of `&str`, so they are `Copy` themselves, so the for loop won't consume them. More explicitly: you can simply use `for suit in suits { for rank in ranks {…}}`.

Comment: Or `into_iter()` instead of `iter()`.

Comment: @EnthusiastMartin `into_iter()` is redundant in `for` loop; you can omit it.